# irrevocable trust - property taxes

Tags: taxes, real-estate, california

I am the trustee of an irrevocable trust, in this trust are two single resident homes with no mortgage. Recently, one home was taken out of this irrevocable trust to get a loan/mortgage.  With this loan, bills are being along with property taxes on each home. 1 home is a primary residence the other a rental.  Since doing this I received a supplemental secured property tax will reason; assessment is in compliance with Article 13A of The California Constitution it reflects the ownership occurring on 7/2020 supplemental bill due to transfer.          Taking the home out of the irrevocable trust was the only way to get a loan/mortgage the home was put back into the I/Trust the same year. I don't understand this ?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Please review your question, a few of the sentences seem to have typos making it a bit difficult to read. Note; This question borders on being more appropriate for Law.SE as part of an answer would also ask how you moved the home out of the trust. If it was a lawyer that did this he should have been aware of this effect, and warned you about it.

Comment: @PATTY What exactly is your question?